# Как изменять админку в django самостоятельно

Tags: html, python, django, django-admin

Я новичек в Django и хочу узнать как я могу редактировать админку Django самостоятельно, а не методами из коробки. К примеру изменять стили, менять цвета, изменять текст, в идеале править html страницу админки, что бы полностью кастомизировать ее, как я хочу.
Какой файл для этого взять нужно и куда засунуть?

Comment: Это сложная тема. Не для новичков.

Comment: Мистер Фикс, ничего сложного не вижу, достаточно использовать стандартное переопределение. Причем можно выборочно, вплоть до страницы, в общем-то как и в друпале было когда-то, подложил свой файл шаблона по пути и все перезаписалось.

Comment: @Igor, может вы и правы.

Comment: @МистерФикс сложное начинается когда не зная основ попробуют например шаблон change_form.html изменить, в остальном специально для переносимости статика и шаблоны в папке приложения, но там же они и по причине переделать не меняя всех на каждом сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Админка в джанго всего лишь дополнительное приложение, и редактируется так же просто. Ничего сложного нет, если конечно не "пилить" универсальное для всех.

В папке приложения admin лежат шаблоны, https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin

В нашем проекте есть папка **templates**. Если мы хотим изменить какой-то шаблон, предположим что общий для всех страниц, для админки это base.html, то смотрим на его путь **templates/admin/base.html** и копируем его в наш проект, с тем же путем.

После чего внутри нашей папки меняем его как захотим, подключая стили и т.п.

**Основной недостаток** - при изменении шаблона при обновлении версии django, наш шаблон не меняется.

Это не единственный способ масштабного изменения, но самый простой для новичка. Если нужно просто добавить скрипт к странице редактирования, то в файле admin.py можно указать путь к скрипту.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы изменить css, нужно изменить файлы лежащие на компьютере по такому пути:
`C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\css`
Но, тогда это будет применяться везде.

Про изменение шаблона:
Нужно редактировать `DIRS` в списке `TEMPLATES`, который лежит в файле настройках проекта. А именно - присвоить ему список из одного элемента: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`.

Так же в корневой папке проекта надо разместить папку `templates`, а в ней папку `admin` и уже в неё вставлять шаблоны, взятые из пути (так на моём компьютере):
`C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin.`
Тогда сам Django будет смотреть в первую очередь на эти шаблоны.

Подробнее см. ссылку: [Writing your first Django app, part 7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial07/)

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ. Привести одну ссылку мало для аргументированного ответа.

Comment: ну вот, а вообще мне в ответе что ли нужно перевести то, что написано по ссылке? Человек не смог найти, я ему помог

Comment: а, или тут такакя система, что в ответы нужно писать только много, а остальное в комменты? тогда я не знал, извините))

Comment: О том какая тут "система" вы прочли в справке, за что и получили знак "Информированный" .

Comment: " Человек не смог найти, я ему помог" - у ТС уже есть принятый им ответ. Вы считаете, что он бесполезный?

Comment: На половину, я не проверял, сработает ли то, что там написали, но в оф документации написано, что нужно ещё немного подправить файл настроек. Плюс там ещё всякие полезные штуки. Конечно тому, кто спросил уже пофиг на этот вопрос, за 8 месяцев он мог стать профи в джанго, но новичкам, которые не смотрели страничку из оф документации, на которую я сослался, она может помочь